# Catching SQL error on future failure in Slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

The code below uses Slick 3.1.x to read a row from a table, attempting to catch any SQL errors. `UserDB` is the Slick representation of the table, and `User` is the related object.

This code does not compile in the `failure` statement with the following error:

> type mismatch; found : Unit required:
>   scala.concurrent.Future[Option[user.manage.User]]

How to fix this to catch the SQL error?

```
   def read (sk: Int): Future[Option[User]] = {
      val users = TableQuery[UserDB]
      val action = users.filter(_.sk === sk).result
      val future = db.run(action)
      future.onSuccess {
        case result =>
              if (!result.isEmpty)
                  Some(result(0))
              else
                  None
      }
      future.onFailure {   // <-- compilation error
          case e => println (e.getMessage)
          None
      }
   }
```

Comment: `onFailure` reigsters a callback and returns `Unit`. Therefore your entire method returns `Unit`.

Comment: Thanks. Assume that on failure I need to write an entry in a log and return `None` (as opposed to return `Some` if the record is read correctly), what should be the approach?

Comment: Don't use `onFailure` but on of the methods on `Future` that can handle an Exception and still return something.

Comment: My objective is to catch (somehow) the SQL exception, taking into consideration that the function returns a Future with an option. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `asTry` method to catch exception ex into a successful result Failure(ex) and the successful value in Success(v). In your case the following should work.

```
db.run(action.asTry).map{
  case Failure(ex) => { 
         Log.error(s"error : ${ex.getMessage}") 
         None
        }
  case Success(x) => x
}
```

As mentioned in the [slick documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/api/index.html#slick.dbio.DBIOAction@asTry:DBIOAction[Try[R],NoStream,E]), `asTry` is used to pipeline the exceptions for recovery handling logic.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the onComplete method of the future.

```
        future.onComplete{
            case Success(r) ⇒ ...
            case Failure(t) ⇒ log.error("failure in db query " + t.getMessage)
        }
```